# c++ inserting values into arrays using a template function

Tags: c++

I am trying to insert a value into the sorted arrays in the right place using a template function. I have the program working if the number is the biggest or the smallest in the array, but not if it's in the middle. So my question is what kind of for loop/if statement combination do I need to get a middle number into the right place?

```
template <class T, class S> 
void insertAndSort(T myArr[], S sizeOf, T itemInsert) {
  for (int i = sizeOf - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (i == sizeOf - 1 && myArr[i] < itemInsert) {
      myArr[i] = itemInsert;
    } else if (i == 0 && myArr[i] > itemInsert) {
      for (int j = sizeOf -1; j >= 0; j--) {
        myArr[j + 1] = myArr[j]; 
      }
      myArr[i] = itemInsert;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  //int array
   const int SIZE_OF = 10;
   int intArr[SIZE_OF] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};

   cout << "Original int array" << endl;

   for(int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF; i++) {
    cout << intArr[i] << " ";
   }

   cout << endl << "int array after inserting 5, 25, and 65" << endl;

   int a = 5;
   int b = 25;
   int c = 65;

   insertAndSort(intArr, 5, a);
   insertAndSort(intArr, 6, b);
   insertAndSort(intArr, 7, c);

   for(int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF; i++) {
    cout << intArr[i] << " ";
   }

  //char array
   char charArr[SIZE_OF] = {'E', 'J', 'O', 'T', 'Y'};

   cout << endl << endl << "Original char array" << endl;

   for(int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF; i++) {
    cout << charArr[i] << " ";
   }

   cout << endl << "char array after inserting B, M, and Z" << endl;

   char d = 'B';
   char e = 'M';
   char f = 'Z';

   insertAndSort(charArr, 5, d);
   insertAndSort(charArr, 6, e);
   insertAndSort(charArr, 7, f);

   for(int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF; i++) {
    cout << charArr[i] << " ";
   }
```

OUTPUT

```
Original int array
10 20 30 40 50 0 0 0 0 0 
int array after inserting 5, 25, and 65
5 10 20 30 40 50 65 0 0 0 

Original char array
E J O T Y      
char array after inserting B, M, and Z
B E J O T Y Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have the program working if the number is the biggest or the smallest in the array, but not if it's in the middle.

Yes, your `for` loop is misleading because it appears to consider all elements from the last to the first, but all it contains is two `if` cases for the last and first elements!  You haven't written any code for the middle portion.

Rather than considering the last and first elements as special cases, you should devise a single algorithm that works for all positions.  First you loop to find the position where the new element must be inserted, then you shift elements on the right one position farther to the right, then you assign the new value where it belongs.  That's really just two separate `for` loops, they do not need to be nested as in your current code.

Comment: This is your assignment, please try to write the code.  It may help to draw on paper how the elements move in a few different cases.

Answer (score -1):

i recommend you use binary search that customize for this problem
you can find near location index with binary search algorithm and then shift rights items by 1 or for remove you can shift left items to remove that item
i'll add sample code in later

This is a full example
i hope this will help you

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void showArray(int* array, int length);

int findNearIndex(int* array, int length, int num);
int findIndex(int* array, int length, int num);

int shiftArray(int* array, int length, int startPos, bool toRight);

bool add(int* array, int& length, int num);
bool remove(int* array, int& length, int num);

int findUpperIndex(int* array, int length, int num);
int findLowerIndex(int* array, int length, int num);

int main()
{
    int num = 8;
    int arr[32];
    int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        arr[i] = i / 4;
    }
    showArray(arr, len);
    cout << "find upper index (" << num << ") = " << findUpperIndex(arr, len, num) << '\n';
    cout << "find Lower index (" << num << ") = " << findLowerIndex(arr, len, num) << '\n';
}
int findUpperIndex(int* array, int length, int num){
    int left = 0;
    int right = length - 1;
    int mid;
    while (left <= right){
        mid = (left + right) / 2;
        if (array[mid] <= num){
            left = mid + 1;
        }
        else {
            right = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    if (num == array[mid -1]){
        if (mid == length - 1 || mid == 0){
            return mid;
        }
        else {
            return mid - 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        return - 1;
    }
}
int findLowerIndex(int* array, int length, int num){
    int left = 0;
    int right = length - 1;
    int mid;
    while (left <= right){
        mid = (left + right) / 2;
        if (array[mid] < num){
            left = mid + 1;
        }
        else {
            right = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    if (num == array[mid]){
        return mid;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
void showArray(int* array, int length){
    cout << "\[";
    length--;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        cout << array[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << array[length] << "] = " << length + 1 << '\n' ;
}

int findNearIndex(int* array, int length, int num){
    int L,R,Mid;
    L = 0;
    R = length -1;
    while (L < R){
        Mid = (L + R) / 2;
        if (array[Mid] == num){
            return Mid;
        }
        else if (array[Mid] < num){
            L = Mid + 1;
        }
        else {
            R = Mid - 1;
        }
    }
    return Mid - 1;
}
int findIndex(int* array, int length, int num){
    int index;
    return (index = findNearIndex(array, length, num)) == num ? index : -1;
}
int shiftArray(int* array, int length, int startPos, bool toRight){
    int index;
    if (toRight){
        index = length;
        while (index > startPos){
            array[index] = array[--index];
        }
        return length + 1;
    }
    else {
        if (startPos == 0){
            return length;
        }
        index = startPos;
        while (index < length){
            array[index] = array[++index];
        }
        return length - 1;
    }
}

bool add(int* array, int& length, int num){
    int index = findNearIndex(array, length, num);
    if (array[index] == num){
        return false;
    }
    length = shiftArray(array, length, index, true);
    array[++index] = num;
    return true;
}
```

Edit:
this is a full examples for binary search and insert into sorted array

Comment: Sorry, I should have said I want to do it with for loops and ifs.

Comment: @LiamJones, this *does* solve the problem with loops and if statements. If you specifically need `for` loops, then - for starters this is a weird requirement - but every `while` loop is trivially convertible to a `for` loop.

Comment: You've declared a `remove` function that does nothing. The questioner only wanted help with inserting to a sorted list. This answer tries to help with a whole lot more, so you've made it harder for yourself.

Comment: `int len = sizeof(arr) / 4` should be `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int)`. Not all platforms have 4 byte `int`s.

Comment: yes your right and man this code is was for 4 years a ago sorry about that, i'll fix this

Comment: @AliMirghasemi, no problem. Another way to write it is `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr)`, which means that if you change the data type of `arr` then you don't need to update the line where you calculate `len`. Either way, this method is only safe within the function that created the array with static size.

Comment: thanks for comment
i usually use this in alternative
#define Array_Length(ARR)      (sizeof((ARR)) / sizeof((ARR[0])))